# VP9/WEBM with Chrome for IOS

Tags: google-chrome, video, ios

If Chrome on OSX can play VP9 / webm videos, shouldn't Chrome for IOS also support playing VP9 / webm videos?

My 10.3.2 phone refuses to play even when the page browsed is as simple as:

```
<div style="width: 352px; >
    <video width="352" height="544" controls>
        <source src="/File/Video/18383"
                type="video/webm">
        Sorry, your web browser doesn't support playing these videos.
    </video>
</div>
```

Interestingly it doesn't display the message. Just the play symbol.

Every other browser I download from the App Store does the same thing, which makes me wonder if I am doing something wrong...

Comment: You might want to check our help center to better understand the scope of Superuser

Comment: In what respect is the question bad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39790639/webrtc-support-on-chrome-browser-in-iphone-ipad

According to this post, the answer is no. Because Apple don't allow Apps in their store that implement their own web rendering engines (aka browsers). Therefore every 'browser' currently available on the App store is just a skin on top of the built-in web render, which explicitly doesn't implement VP9 / webm support.